How to optimize token generation by making parallel server calls in Spring Boot with Flux?
I'm working on optimizing a process to generate a stream of tokens and am unsure how to start implementing a more efficient method.
Below, I described the current approach and my idea for improvement and I'm looking for a simple example of how to implement the proposed optimization using Spring Boot with Flux.
Current Approach:

Receive a user query.

Call to Server 1: Fetch a list of integers based on the query. If the list is valid and non-empty, proceed to the next step.

Call to Server 2: Pass the user query and the list from Server 1 to Server 2. The response is a stream of tokens.

Send Data to Frontend: Stream of tokens received from Server 2 and at the end, the list of integers is sent to the frontend.

If the first call results in null or an empty list, the second call is not made.


Proposed Optimization:
I want to make the calls to Server 1 and Server 2 in parallel to enhance the efficiency:

Parallel Calls: Initiate the calls to Server 1 and Server 2 simultaneously.

Buffering: Temporarily store the stream of tokens from Server 2 in a buffer.

Handling Server 1 Response:
a) If indices are returned: Send the buffered tokens to the frontend, then continue streaming any new tokens directly to the frontend.
b) If null or empty: Terminate the Server 2 call and inform the frontend that no information is available.


The first approach was implemented using Flux in Spring Boot. However, I'm unsure about how to implement the buffering and conditional logic for the parallel approach.
How can I efficiently implement this parallel processing model in Spring Boot with Flux? Are there particular patterns or Flux methods that would facilitate managing these concurrent calls and conditional responses based on the results of the first call?

A Flux is already parallel, so not sure what you want to parallize even more.

@M.Deinum. Hi, I've outlined a few additional tasks to accompany parallel API calls. These include buffering the data and, once the condition is met, stream the buffered tokens to the frontend. Subsequently, seamlessly continue streaming any new tokens directly to the frontend.

A Flux is already a stream. Feels like you are doing blocking things (collecting into a list for instance) instead of fully utilizing the Flux async/non-blocking features. Please show some code that you are using, make sure that the dataaccess is also reactive etc.

@M.Deinum Sir, I can't start streaming tokens from Server 2 to frontend until I get data from Server 1. But instead of waiting, I want to get the tokens  from Server 2 and keep saving them in temporary buffer. Once Server 1's data arrives, we'll send the saved tokens to the frontend. After that, we can continue streaming new tokens from server 2 directly to the frontend without storing them. Sorry, i don't have code to the proposed solution.

I'm not asking for code of the proposed solution but of the current solution. But as stated everything is already async and streaming. So not sure what is preventing you from utilizing that.
